# How to find a page in drupal to edit?

Tags: php, drupal, edit

I have a page in Drupal which is coming when clicking on a my account link,
I want to change some content of this page, but I couldn't find page in the script. The URL of the page is

http://localhost/example_drupal/node/8135/edit?destination=sa/view-forms%3Ffield_sd_club_name_value%3Dnes%26field_form_status_value%3DAll

Please anyone help me, how to get the same page in Drupal to edit it?

Comment: So you want to be able to edit the node edit form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easy search nodes use [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module. Module add search field in pages list.

Answer (score 1):

So, url to your page is /node/8135 and url to it's edit page is /node/8135/edit . You got both ulrs there.

Comment: I want to edit the code of edit page not its content. I have to customize it.

Comment: To customize it in what way? To add new fields or to keep same fields and...?

Comment: Just to change a radio button field in that page.

Comment: Again, to change visually existing field or to add/remove a field? For first option try doing it with CSS first. And for second you have to edit that content type. Go under content types, see available fields, edit them..